# FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h not found when using UnitTest

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, preprocessor, file-not-found

I have an application using Facebook Framework and it works fine. 
I wrote a unit test and when I run it, I get this error:

```
Lexical or Preprocessor Issue - FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h file not found ProjectName-Prefix.pch
```

Why does this occur in testing but not in run/build/archive?

Update:
1) Tried always use user...path

2)Cleaned the workspace

None of them worked

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved my problem. I didn't set the Framework Search Paths for MyProjectTest Target. In MyProject Target was set so that why it was failing only in tests